# Redirect user who already logged in PHP

Tags: php

I want to redirect logged in users to home page(member-index.php), I have used the following code to accomplish this, but this doesn't work.

```
<?php

function redirect() {
header('location:member-index.php');
}
 ?> 
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'])){
   redirect();
  }
?> 

<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login-exec.php">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" placeholder="username" />
    <input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="LOGIN" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

session variables at (login-exec.php)

```
 $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['fullname'];
```

The other pages with sessions, works perfectly fine, I could get and print the logged in user on another page, But couldn't get session work in login-form page.. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any call to the header() function needs to be before any output.  It's failing since you are outputting the html first

Comment: Did you start the session for "login-form" and is it present inside all pages using sessions? Plus, using the same conditional statement to check if the sessions are set?

Comment: Yes, `session_start();` is used in all the pages that uses sessions, and all of those work fine.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also use `var_dump();` on the sessions variable(s).

Comment: I've done that before, I couldn't see any warnings or errors.

Comment: I'm surprised error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` didn't throw you a notice about outputting before header. Move your `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of your code. `<?php session_start(); ?><?php

function redirect() {
header('location:member-index.php');
}
 ?>` and add `exit;` after your header.

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login/login-form.php:20) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login/login-form.php on line 6` 

line 6 is the header('location:member-index.php')

Comment: See, I told you. There shouldn't be anything above that. Do `<?php session_start(); ?><?php function redirect() { header('location:member-index.php'); exit; } ?>` then the rest of your code. Change it to that and try it again. If your form or other HTML is above the PHP move it below that.

Comment: Same error, headers already sent :(

Comment: Then you most likely have a BOM (byte order mark) in your file(s). You need to convert to UTF-8 without BOM. You don't have anything else above `session_start();` right? Such as HTML, an include etc. A cookie is also considered as output, JS whatver. You cannot have any type of output before header; period.

Comment: My code looks like this [link](http://prntscr.com/66czqe)

Comment: Even a mere space before your opening `<?php` is output. I think you have BOM issue. You do know what I meant by that earlier, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71105/discussion-between-user2768665-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this code at top of my login form, and it worked!

```
<?php
      //Start session
      session_start();

  //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
  if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("location: member-index.php");
    exit();
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` didn't throw you a warning about outputting before header.

I.e.:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent...

Move your `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of your code.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
function redirect() {
header('location:member-index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

and add `exit;` after your header to avoid further execution.

Also make sure all your files do not contain a byte order mark (BOM) and that there is no output before header. A space, HTML, nothing, not even a cookie, or anything else that would account as output.

- All files should be saved in your code editor, as UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Do this at the top of your file instead

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'])){
        header("location: member-index.php");
    } 
?>
<html>....the rest of your html
```

You can look at the php docs for [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to see why you are having an issue.  The paragraph that starts with 'Remember' specifically

Comment: how can it work without `start_session();` It didnt work